# How to customize EclipseChe menus and plugins

Tags: eclipse-che

I would like to do customization as below in Eclipse Che.
Please share the reference information such as sample etc.

1. Addition of original menu
   Would like to add items in right-click menu of the project and header menu of Eclipse Che.
2. Call of extended-plugin processing from added menu
   From the menu added in 1., would like to call the processing of plugin created originally.
3. Would like to apply the plugin extended in 2. in Eclipse Che.

Comment: Made it a bit more readable but still though it's off-topic here on SO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example for adding toolbar, you can add your menu using the same example.
Please look into this page https://www.eclipse.org/che/docs/assemblies/sdk-actions/index.html

```
  @Extension(title = "Sample Actions Extension", version = "1.0.0")
  public class SampleActionsExtensions {
  @Inject
  public SampleActionsExtensions(HelloWorldAction helloWorldAction, ActionManager actionManager) {

  actionManager.registerAction("helloWorldAction", helloWorldAction);
  actionManager.registerAction("helloWorldActionWithIcon", helloWorldActionWithIcon);
  /...

  DefaultActionGroup sampleGroup = new DefaultActionGroup("Sample actions", true, actionManager);

  sampleGroup.add(helloWorldAction);

  // add sample group after help menu entry
  DefaultActionGroup mainMenu = (DefaultActionGroup)actionManager.getAction(GROUP_MAIN_MENU);
    mainMenu.add(sampleGroup);

  // add the sample group to the beginning of the toolbar as well
  DefaultActionGroup toolbar = (DefaultActionGroup)actionManager.getAction(IdeActions.GROUP_MAIN_TOOLBAR);
  toolbar.add(helloWorldActionWithIcon);
  /...
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I have solved this problem.

Comment: let me know if you have any other questions for CHE customization